# Shortcut to creating assets in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop, document-setup

Does anyone know a shortcut to select a layer in photoshop, open up a new file that automatically is the correct size, or even has the element in it without having to drag in a new document and then crop it to size or guess the size?

For example I made a design comp of a website I"m making. I want to copy the logo layer and save it as a png to use as an asset on the site. Looking for a quick way to do that.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layer > Duplicate Layer and set the destination to new[image]

and then you can trim the transparent. 
[image]

I would suggest setting it up as actions so you can do it at the click of a button.

Comment: @user2684452   In Photoshop CC and CC 2014 there is [Assets generator](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html). There are also many third party plugins and scripts that also work in older versions. Many of them have extra features.