# Copy Layer(s) into new automatically sized file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What I want to do is to be able to copy either a layer or a group of layers into a new document which is sized to that layers exact dimensions. I find I can right click -> Duplicate -> New Document, but it is still sized the same as the original document. Is there any way to make it so that the new document will be sized precisely to fit the layer(s)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you duplicate the new layer you can trim the transparency. For one click use you can set both of these things up as actions.

[image]

The user, Joonas also made me aware [last time I saw this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38153/shortcut-to-creating-assets-in-photoshop/38154#38154) of [the Assets Generator](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html), which also may be of use to you.